# How to differentiate multiple instances of the same method bound to an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding, event-handling

Say you have a class `Foo`, and multiple objects of this class have their method `bar()` bound to an element's `click` event (see the code snippet below). After clicking that element, I would expect the console to show the following:

```
name: a
name: b
name: c
```

But only the last object's `bar()` method gets called:

```
name: c
```

Why is this? Why aren't the others called? I suspect it is because of `$.off()`, and if this is the case, is there a way to differentiate between calling `$.off()` and `$.on()` for each individual object's `bar()` method?

```js
function Foo(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Foo.prototype.bar = function (e) {
    var foo = e.data.foo;
    console.log("name:", foo.name);
}

$.each(["a","b","c"], function (index, value) {
    var $elem = $("#button-test");
    var obj = new Foo(value);

    $elem.off("click", obj.bar); // To ensure each object's method isn't bound multiple times
    $elem.on("click", { foo: obj }, obj.bar);
});
```

```html
<button id="button-test" type="button">Test</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using `obj.bar.bind(obj)`:

```js
function Foo(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log("name:", this.name);
}

$.each(["a","b","c"], function (index, value) {
    var $elem = $("#button-test");
    var obj = new Foo(value);
    var barEvent = obj.bar.bind(obj); // Added this
    $elem.off("click", barEvent); // To ensure each object's method isn't bound multiple times
    $elem.on("click", barEvent);
});
```

```html
<button id="button-test" type="button">Test</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```